# CM4 carrier board design, what to do with GLOBAL_EN?

Tags: boot, power

I'm designing a simple carrier board for CM4, I don't need a power switch, I just want it to run and boot as soon as I plug the power. What should I do with GLOBAL_EN and nRPIBOOT pins to make it happen? Should I just leave them unconnected or do I need to pull them up or down?